# How to find app name / intent name to open an android app

Tags: android, google-play

I am looking to find out how to open my open app using another app.
E.g. I know I can open

1. google play store by using market://<page_name>
2. instagram by using instagram://<page_name>

similarly I would like to know where to find this app name for my app. I tried my app's name but it did not work.
I tried myapp_name://login

Answer (score 0):

Use an implicit intent in android.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer to help others understand :)